# Synchronization method in WCF

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, synchronization

I write the WCF application. In service i have method and i want sync this method to all customers. So one client can use this method at the moment and rest client waiting when first client finish. I try `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` but this not work. This is my service class

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary1 {
    [ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
    public class Service1 : IService1 {


        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        public List<String> getBrute() {
           //method body
        }
     }
}
```

How does synchronization methods in WCF?

Comment: Your method would have worked if you had set [`InstanceContextMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx) to `Single` and [`ConcurrencyMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode.aspx) to `Multiple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that setting only really makes sense in the context of a duplex binding (a callback) where the client has registered a callback from the server **to** the client. It is a slightly exotic situation. It basically says *when you receive this callback from the server invoke it onto the main thread, rather than just running it on some arbitrary thread pool thread.*

To do what you want, you need to create an explicit lock on the server:

```
public class Service1 : IService1 {
    private static readonly object @lock = new object();

    public List<String> getBrute() {
       lock (@lock)
       {
           //method body
       }
    }
 }
```